# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string in C:\xampp\htdocs\em0126\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php:555 Stack trace: #0

Tags: magento, phpmyadmin, xampp

I am facing these errors while accessing Magento folder from XAMPP (localhost/magento):

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\em0126\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php:555
>   Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\em0126\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(390):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput() #1
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\em0126\app\code\core\Mage\Install\controllers\WizardController.php(120):
>   Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout() #2
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\em0126\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(418):
>   Mage_Install_WizardController->beginAction() #3
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\em0126\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Router\Standard.php(250):
>   Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('begin') #4
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\em0126\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Front.php(172):
>   Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http)) #5 > C:\xampp\htdocs\em0126\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch() #6
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\em0126\app\Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Mo in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\em0126\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php on
>   line 555

Answer (score 110):

Your solution

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string in ...
>   app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php:555 ...

This error was easy to fix because the problem was in the following line:

```
$out .= $this->getBlock($callback[0])->$callback[1]();
```

Instead it should be:

```
$out .= $this->getBlock($callback[0])->{$callback[1]}();
```

find your detail solution here on below given link

http://www.code007.ro/making-work-magento-with-php-7-rc1/

Comment: It s working fine only, When will add the layout.php $out .= $this->getBlock($callback[0])->{$callback[1]}();

Comment: Worked for me, probably a PHP7 issue

Comment: Works great, thanks! I don't know why that error line is still present in the default Magento installation. Beats the hell out of me.

Comment: I am having php 5.6 and was having this issue, and after given solution it is resolved, but now I am not able to login in admin panel, not sure what to do next?

Answer (score 28):

Its due to PHP7

It's not recommended to edit the core file. We will override it.

Copy this file `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php` into `app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php`

Change code in `app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php` file (line # 555)

```
$out .= $this->getBlock($callback[0])->$callback[1]();
```

To:

```
$out .= $this->getBlock($callback[0])->{$callback[1]}();
```

Comment: You can create "local" folder and other subdirectories if not present.

Comment: Thanks really helped me. I wasted 1 whole day trying to fix but this helped me! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 20):

Changed the line 555 to:

```
$out .= $this->getBlock($callback[0])->{$callback[1]}();
```

It works. But one thing I'm not sure of if this is really a php7. I'm running this on my website with same files and configurations on the same server and it's working with no issues without changing that line.

Comment: The other site probably uses PHP5, and not PHP7 :)

Answer (score 12):

Go to app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php line no 555 and

```
 change $callback[1] to {$callback[1]}
```

Answer (score 7):

it is a php7 issue since when i upgraded from 5.6 to 7.0 i got this error. to fixe it i edited core file (hope a patch will come soon) either like mentionned in other ansewers before or like below:

Go to app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php line no 555

```
$method = $callback[1];
$out .= $this->getBlock($callback[0])->$method();
```