# Issue after Magento Migration to AWS

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, magento, magento-1.9

I am new to Magento, I have a task to migrate the Existing website built with Magento to AWS cloud(EC2)

Existing Magento Version - 1.9.1.1. I do not want to Upgrade it, as it is out of our scope of work.

I have Migrated all the source files and Database from old server to EC2 instance, So far so good.
After i point the DNS A record to new IP address, a blank page was showing, further on debugging and browsing stackoverflow
changed as per [Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string in C:\xampp\htdocs\em0126\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php:555 Stack trace: #0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35611696/fatal-error-uncaught-error-function-name-must-be-a-string-in-c-xampp-htdocs-e)
from 
$out .= $this->getBlock($callback[0])->$callback1;
to
$out .= $this->getBlock($callback[0])->{$callback[1]}();

Web Pages are Partially loading.

Now below lines are getting displayed on home page and Product detailed page is also not working

```
getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('banner-block')->toHtml(); ?>
getChildHtml('cms_footer_links') ?> getChildHtml('footer_links') ?>
```

Please Help in getting this resolved.

New Environment running on  - PHP 7.2/Mysql/Apache

URL : http://viviscal.ae/

Comment: What was the Php version on the previous environment?

Comment: Earlier it was PHP 5 and now php 7

Comment: Also comment are there Like Below statements. 
<?php// echo $this->getChildHtml('cms_footer_links') ?> <?php// echo $this->getChildHtml('footer_links') ?>

Comment: Try to comment like <?php // echo $this->getChildHtml('cms_footer_links') ?> 
<?php // echo $this->getChildHtml('footer_links') ?>

Give space after <?php tag

Answer (score 0):

need to enable short_open_tag in php.ini or Through HTACCESS.

In mycase - php.ini  didnt work so added through HTACCESS

```
php_value short_open_tag 1
```